# SQL Auto Insert - Time-format -time is 10 hours difference?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my SQL Server variables and settings system time zone is given as MST.
I am trying to change the time zone to london its not working
Adding 10 hours manually in PHP code is not an option because,the server is accessed by android and iphones.

i Tried  in the databse

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone
```

which showed

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql&gt; SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone' at line 1
```

Comment: You added `mysql > ` at the beginning of your MySQL query. Delete that.

Comment: Thanks,but it says #1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

Comment: should I execute the sql in the table or in the server which contains the database ? anyway i tried both   #1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

Comment: That's self-explanatory. Log in to mysql as a super user and try again. EDIT: It's a global setting; it doesn't matter where you set it.

Comment: @Palladium Sorry i am the only person using the sql ,and have only only one login,which i am using right now

Comment: @Tom Well someone set up that access for you since you obviously aren't logged in a root user (which typically you shouldn't be).  SO you should be able to have that person either do this for you or give you SUPER permission so you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server

```
ALTER DATABASE your-database-name SET TIMEZONE TO 'your-timezone';
```

Comment: not working #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET TIMEZONE TO 'Europe/London'' at line 1

Comment: Read please: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/285850/settings-database-mysql-time-zone-help

Answer (score 0):

'mysql>' should not be part of the query.  It looks like you copied right from mysql documentation, which is good that you are looking at the right place.  Just understand that when you see 'mysql>'  that is just indicating a command line prompt (i.e. if operating in MySQL at the command prompt).